# How do I make two divs the same level

Tags: html, css, frontend

How do you make 2 `div`s the same height? Does it change based on the HTML? I've tried stuff like: `vertical-align:center` for both items without it causing the change I am desiring.

```
<p class='a'>asadads
</p>
<p class='b'>asdadsadsasd
</p>
```

Comment: When you say 'vertical' do you mean you have two <p>s and you want the text to be at the same height in those <p>s?  Or you want them side by side?  Or are you referring to their height on the z-index?

Comment: do you mean p.a is on the left, p.b is on the right, and their top alignment to the parent div is equal?

Comment: is class a already in float left ? .a{float: left;}

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with;

http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/KbpAh/

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p class='a'>asadads
</p>
<p class='b'>asdadsadsasd
</p>

</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper{}
.a, .b{
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#eee;
    color:#585858;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.a{border:1px solid #ff0000;}
.b{border:1px solid #0000FF;}
```

I created an outer wrapper to hold both

s.  I then floated .a and .b so their layout aligns together.  Then I defined identical padding for both

s so content within each aligns properly.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a `div` outside with a set width in order to be vertically aligned or you could use the same margin on each `p` tag.

Also use: `text-align:center;` not `vertical-align`

```
p {
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonocairns/rQMyd/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need `display:inline;`,right?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zhang6464/df8ba/)

Answer (score -1):

You can make them display inline by setting their display property:

```
p.a, p.b {
  display: inline-block
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/hULPghSet0JKQgkj2g6i?p=preview